# php artisan horizon:install returns "Could not open input file: artisan"

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I've seen answers for this question, but I'm still really confused, because answers say I need to be in my Laravel's project folder, which I thought I had created.

I'm trying to run the command php

> php artisan horizon:install

This is the second step in the Laravel installation guide found here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/horizon#installation

My directory structure looks like this in my documents folder in Mac OS:

[image]

I've tried running the command in the RetimeWeb, vendor, bin, laravel and horizon folders. What am I doing wrong here? Where is an artisan folder supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel Horizon is dashboard for managing queues (jobs) in Laravel that supposed to be installed on top of Laravel project.

Based on your directory structure you installed Horizon from composer alone. Now you are trying to run command "php artisan horizon:install" but artisan is a tool from Laravel.
"horizon:install" supposed to copy all assets, configs etc to Laravel project - but again, you do not have any so there is not even where to copy it.

To summary.

1. Install Laravel.
2. Install Laravel Horizon.

Comment: I have no idea what lead me down this path of installing Horizon first, but now I'm using this guide to install Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x

Answer (score 0):

Do `cd` until you're in the root folder of your project and run the command again. `artisan` file is in the root folder of a laravel project

Comment: Isn't the folder "RealtimeWeb" the root folder of my Laravel project? That's what I specified when choosing a place where my project resides.

Comment: It doesn't look like it. The root folder should contain app, database, routes, resources and vendor folders. i